# Obtain div tag height

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have div tag, in this div tag,  I write results from database (with PHP / MYSQL).
I want alert height   this div tag. Problem is that, sometimes alert returns incorrect  div height (less than real result). sometimes result is correct.

I think, this happens, because javascript returns result before, than php finishes their work
and  on this is result less than, real height div tag. someone know how solve this problem?
(apropos, incorrect alert result, is only chrome and safari, in opera and firefox result always  real.)
this is php code:

```
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT some_column FROM table");
echo '<div id="my_div">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo '<p>'.row[0].'</p>';
}
echo "</div>";
```

and js code:

```
$(document).ready ( function () {

   alert( $("#my_div").height() );

});
```

Comment: How far off are chrome & safari?

Comment: How do you determine the correct height? How do you know it's wrong?

Comment: The PHP will always run before your JS (unless you are loading it piece by piece via ajax), so it shouldn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: You might want outerHeight. Depends on what you need.

Comment: @ mcpDESIGNS Your question is about version yes? this browser versions is last

Comment: @Paul, I know because sometimes result is very many, approximately for example 3000 px is div tag height and alert returns: 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calculate height after page loaded,

```
window.onload = function (){
    alert( $("#my_div").height() );
}
```

Comment: `.ready` runs when the DOM is ready, but that doesn't mean that it has "settled."  Graphics, for instance, may still need to load.  `onload` runs after the page is complete.

Comment: Thanks very much, when I change "$(document).ready" on "window.onload", the problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `outerHeight` method 
http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/